Utilizando permalinks personalizados en WordPress
Estoy con un sitio de WordPress donde estoy implementando un permalink personalizado para filtrar/agrupar posts, utilizo la siguiente estructura
/%location%/%postname%/

donde %location% es una taxonomia personalizada con esa etiqueta que agregue para agrupar todos los posts que pertencen a una misma localidad, y utilizo ese script para que las URL de los posts pueden ser funcionales:
function custom_taxonomy_permalink($permalink, $post, $leavename) {    
  if ($post->post_type === 'post') {
    $terms = get_the_terms($post, 'location');
    if (empty($terms)) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    $term_slug = array_pop($terms)->slug;    
    $permalink = str_replace('%location%', $term_slug, $permalink);
  }

  return $permalink;
}

add_filter('post_link', 'custom_taxonomy_permalink', 10, 3);

Esto funciona excelente para los propositos del sitio pero tengo un problemita tambien, necesito agregar solo una pagina para un mensaje de politica de privacidad y parece que esto esta interfiriendo con los slugs de Wordpress porque me devuelve un 404, por ejemplo si la pagina es algo como /privacidad, no la reconoce y devuelve la plantilla del 404, y estoy seguro que es el permalink, porque cuando lo devuelvo a solo %postname% funciona bien, pero me deshago del filtro que estoy ocupando para los posts.
Alguna ayuda o guia se les aprecia mucho para resolver esto.

Te has planteado agregar esa pagina como un banner de Cookies con un link a esa pagina de privacidad?? Lo puedes hacer con un Snippet sin necesidad de guardarlos siquiera en la DB y mucho menos sin usar un Plugin

Lo que sucede es que estas modificando directamente la Permalink Structure, eso afecta de forma global.
Lo que podrías intentar es poner otra linea con mayor prioridad que reescriba los permalinks para las paginas. Por ejemplo:
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 5, 0);
function custom_rewrite_rule() {

    $pages = get_pages();
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        add_rewrite_rule('^' . $page->post_name . '/?', 'index.php?pagename=' . $page->post_name, 'top');
    }
    
}

Esto usa el action init con prioridad 5, obtiene todas las páginas y agrega nuevas reglas de escritura para ellas.
Agrégalo a tu functions.php o plugin y luego recarga los enlaces permanentes.
Lo único malo es que deberas recargar los enlaces permanentes cada vez que crees una página para que los enlaces permanentes vuelvan a crearse.
Talvez puedas hacerlo al guardar un post/pagina, tipo.
function my_save_post_function($post_id, $post, $update) {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('save_post', 'my_save_post_function', 20, 3);

Pero no lo he probado así que no estoy seguro si funcionara.

Agradecido capo, algo habia leido en otro post sobre un rewrite rule, pero su implementacion esta mucho mas sencilla y entendible
